# How to stop/cancel a training session(Python)?

Tags: flask, cancellation

I have a function "train_model" which is call via a "train" (Flask) API. Once this API is triggered training of a model is started. On completion it saves a model. But I want to introduce a "cancel" API. Which will stop the training, and should return a valid response for "train" API.

Comment: please update the question title related to the question of the flask and python too

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider using multiprocessing and run that model in a separate process and respond with a unique request_id, which is stored in the cache/db later whenever you want to cancel, so when model training is complete before exiting the process remove it from cache/db and your API should take request_id and stop that process or if it is not cache/db respond 404 accordingly since this way work is too much of re-inventing wheel you could simply consider using celery

sample untested code with multiprocessing pool

```
jobs = {}
    @app.route("/api/train", methods=['POST'])
       def train_it():
          with Pool() as process_pool:
            job = process_pool.apply_async(train_model_func,args=(your_inputs))
            job['12455ABC'] = job

          return "OK I got you! here is your request id 12455ABC"
```